# Sending Text to GCM

Tags: android, sms, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an android project where client needed to send just a single sms/text (yes, sms only) to GCM like server and GCM service will handle delivery of message to thousand of target Android devices. I am in doubt whether it is possible or not. I searched a lot but not found a reliable answer anywhere.

Comment: How did you find out that the answers you found were not reliable? Did you try the proposed solutions? If so, what was the problem with those? We can help better if you start with something.

Comment: I wanted to send sms to perticular phone no. which then push text message to GCM server. I have to try it with JSON or HTTP only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible to accomplish this with GCM. This is exactly what GCM was made for. Follow the instructions from Google and you'll be good to go.
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Alternatively, if you only want to send an sms, why don't you just send an sms...

Comment: One solution found free SMSSync is to receive SMS messages from user, and forward them via HTTP(S) to a server. This will do the rest. Thanks